# What are rules of thumb for setting Isolation Forest tuning parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

I am trying to learn how to set input parameter values for the Isolation Forest class. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063031/how-to-use-isolation-forest) SO answer and the Isolation Forest documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html), but am unclear on how to go about tweaking the values of the parameters (n_estimators, max_samples, max_features) for a given data set. Aside from [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54873/isolation-forest-sklearn-contamination-param) discussion of the contamination parameter, I haven't found a good discussion anywhere of the process of setting the parameter values. Could someone please shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: Why the -1 rating?